# Format Range when cell value entered

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template where the user enters account information and the default range for information is range B18 to S52. This fits nicely onto the screen and is a big enough range for the details being entered 90% of the time. However on a few occasions the use may have data that is a few hundred rows. Its usally copied and pasted in but would make the sheet look messy as it would be out of the default range.

I'm trying make the formatting dynamic where by if the user enters data outside of the default range a macro is triggered that will count the rows and reformat the range.

The code I have so far from researching online is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = "$B$18" Then
        Call CountLoc
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub CountLoc()

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    '.Calculation = xlManual
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Dim LocCount As Long
Dim WsInput As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set WsInput = Sheets("Account Input")

With WsInput
    LocCount = .Range("B1048576").End(xlUp).row - 17
End With

If LocCount > 35 Then

Set rng = WsInput.Range(WsInput.Cells(18, 2), WsInput.Cells(17 + LocCount, 19))

With rng
    .Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241)
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders.Color = vbBlack
    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
End With

For i = 1 To LocCount Step 2

Rows(18 + i).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbWhite

Next i

Else

Exit Sub

End If
```

This essentially colors every other row light blue and white and adds a border to each cell. The Count Loc works fine and does what I need it to do but the problem I have is that I cannot get the worksheet_Change to trigger.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at formula based conditional formatting?  Is the code in the correct sheet.

Comment: I did take a look at conditional formatting but was unsure how to make it dynamic. Especially when I'm not sure of the final row count. If I put conditional formatting in 100 rows then the use gets a dataset with 200 rows it falls over? Thats how I understand it? Could be wrong?

Comment: Look at using dynamic named ranges, basically, it's a name as you've probably used, but it's a formula to define, so instead of "A1:A100" you'd have it set at `offset(a1,0,0,counta(a:a),1)` this will expand from a1 to the amount of rows.  Im not saying your approach is wrong, but sometimes Excel can do what you want.

Comment: So, I had data from cell A1, to x rows deep.  I created a name called TEST_NAME, in the refers to, I put `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A),1)` and then had conditional formatting, where the applies to is TEST_NAME.  You can see that the `COUNTA` will do what you are doing with `.end(xlUp)`  This wont work first off for you as I am using A1:Ax, so you'll need to adjust (as you have with your -17)

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I can kind of see what its doing but my experience with named ranges and formulas and conditional formatting is limited. Currently tearing my hair out trying to make it work!

Answer (score 0):

there

I ran a little test using your code and the first thing I noticed, is that you set the `Application.EnableEvents to False` and you don't set it back on, so you are cancelling any event like the `Worksheet_Change Event` once that's fix the event will trigger any time the cell B18 changes, except if the value that is entered comes from a paste(not sure why) but if you use the Intersect method then it works even if the value came from a copy paste.

I did some small tweeks to your code and I think it works now. please review it and give it a try.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Account Input").Range("B18")) Is Nothing Then
   Call CountLoc
End If
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub CountLoc()

Dim LocCount As Long
Dim WsInput As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set WsInput = Sheets("Account Input")

With WsInput
 LocCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

If LocCount > 35 Then

Set rng = WsInput.Range(WsInput.Cells(18, 2), WsInput.Cells(LocCount, 19))

With rng
    .Interior.Color = RGB(220, 230, 241)
    .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Borders.Color = vbBlack
    .Borders.Weight = xlThin
End With

For i = 18 To LocCount Step 2

Set rng = WsInput.Range(WsInput.Cells(i, 2), WsInput.Cells(i, 19))
rng.Interior.Color = vbWhite

Next i

Else

Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```